# Plot is only visible after two draw commands

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I execute the following Code, the plot at first is only white, and only after the second iteration of the loop, it shows the data,axis,etc.

Yet if I uncomment the second fig.canvas.draw() command, the whole plot gets visible immediately in the first loop iteration.
Is this supposed to be that way or am I missing something?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot()
im = ax.plot(np.random.random(5))
plt.show(block=False)
val_accuracy = np.random.random(30)*5
for i in range(30):
    print(i)
    ax.clear()
    val_accuracy[i] = i
    im = ax.plot(val_accuracy)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    #fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.1)

plt.show(block = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single call to `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` instead - alternatively you could use `fig.canvas.show()` (which calls `draw_idle` internally)

Conversely, `draw` will attempt to render your plot immediately, even if there's no output to show.

Comment: If I use figure.canvas.show() it says AttributeError:'FigureCanvasTKAgg' object has no attribute 'show' and if I use fig.canvas.draw_idle() nothing happens at all. This somehow doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's possible/likely that the call to `sleep` is interfering with the GUI event loop and breaking `draw_idle`. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to test this at the moment, so it's just a theory...